# How do I iterate through a list until I have found an element

Tags: python, list, for-loop, iteration

This program checks through a file full of passwords until it matches the valid password.

```
b=open('passy.txt','r')
pass_check=b.readlines()

for i in pass_check:
    pname.append(i)

for i in pname:


    if passvalid in pname:
        print("Password is correct")
        break
    else:
        print("Password isnt correct")
b.close()
```

How can I stop execution of the code when it finds a match?

Comment: I don't understand the intended logic. Could you show a small example of the file contents, an example of `passvalid`, and what output you expect?

Comment: passvalid would be the password the user entered upon registering, and that would be saved into a file, and when they put that passowrd back in, the program would iterate through the file to check if it is a valid passcode

Comment: I think you're confused, cause `for i in pname` and `if passvalid in pname` don't make any sense together. You could either use just `if passvalid in pname` or `for i in pname: if i == passvalid: ... break`

Comment: By the way, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and you might want to read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stop execution of a for or while loop, use `break`. Also not using a with statement when opening files is bad coding practice. A with statement automatically closes the file after you are done with it.

Edit: By any chance, I read over your code and it seems like you’re trying to check if the valid password is equal to the i-th element of an integer, which is obviously incorrect.

```
with open('passy.txt','r') as b:
    pass_check=b.readlines()

for i in range(len(pass_check)):
    pname.append(i)
passlength=int(len(pname))

for i in range(passlength):

    if passvalid == passlength[i]:
        print("Password is correct")
        break
    else:
        print("Password isn't correct")
```

Comment: b=open('passy.txt','r')
    pass_check=b.readlines()


    for i in pass_check:
        pname.append(i)

    for i in pname:


        if passvalid in pname:
            print("Password is correct")
            break
        else:
            print("Password isnt correct")
    b.close()

Comment: @TP123 umm is that not the code I wrote? Why paste it here

Comment: The while loop isnt recognised when put as b in my versio of python

Comment: @TP123 what version of python are you running?

Comment: @TP123 3.7 has a while loop

Comment: @TP123 oh sorry I meant `with`

Comment: if passvalid == passlength[i]:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @TP123 that’s your error. Try checking pass_check[i]

Comment: Passcheck[i] is somehow showing integers in a list? How can i get it to stop doing this

Comment: @TP123 What is in the file?

Comment: I am now getting this error for i in range(pass_check):
TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Comment: Oh sorry misread your question. In the file passy, there are passwords that people have entered in the registeration

Answer (score 0):

> How can I stop execution of the code when it finds a match?

You could encapsulate your logic in a method and use the `return` statement in that method when a match has been found.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by your question, but FWIW it seems like you're overcomplicating things. Try this instead:

```
passvalid = 'hunter2'

with open('passy.txt') as b:
    pname = (s.rstrip('\n') for s in b)
    if passvalid in pname:
        print("Password is correct")
    else:
        print("Password isn't correct")
```

Here both `b` and `pname` are iterators, so once `passvalid` is found, they stop being evaluated.